# What software to represent hierarchical objects as a tree

Tags: database, configuration-management

In my current project, we have several components (some are hardware and software, other are pure software) and all of them require some configurations.
Usually, the configuration is a file containing parameters, but sometimes, it can be more complex (set of files, binaries etc).

There can also be relationship between components, but more in a hierarchical way (e.g. parameters of a top component that may apply to sub-components).

As a naïve approach, I guess I can represent my components as objects with attributes.

So, as a first start, I would like to find a software that can:

- Create instances of objects with a GUI
- Order and display the objects in a tree
- Store the objects (and the attributes) in a database

Do you know if such a software is available?
Ideally, the software is open source and running under Linux!

Comment: For what OS? Must it be free, or how much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: You could use Adobe AIR SDK for a UI renderer, which takes, say, XML data. It can be built quickly on top of DisplayObjects

Comment: @Izzy: yes, must be free and ideally for Linux.

Comment: Argh, tapped into my own trap. Free as RMS, free as free beer, or both? I.e. F(L)OSS, or just "no money paid"? One more hint: You can always [edit] your own posts and add those details yourself ;)

Comment: Ahah thanks for the hints. Maybe you have some ideas with non open-source softwares?